# Why does Haskell use -> instead of =?

Tags: haskell, language-design

Why does Haskell use "->" where it seemingly could have just used "="?

For example, what's wrong with this?

```
take m ys               = case (m,ys) of
                            (0,_)       =  []
                            (_,[])      =  []
                            (n,x:xs)    =  x : take (n-1) xs
```

or

```
(\x = x * x)
```

Comment: Well, for my eyes, this looks a little confused.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It would be unfortunate to write

```
(0, _) = []
```

because that is not true.

In the tradition of Robert Recorde, we try to write equations only when we intend the left-hand side to equal the right-hand side. So we write

```
dup x = (x, x)
```

to make `dup x` equal to `(x, x)`, or

```
dup = \ x -> (x, x)
```

to make `dup` equal to the function which maps `x` to `(x, x)`, but not

```
\ x = (x, x)
```

because there is no way to make `x` equal `(x, x)`.

We depart from the tradition only slightly when we allow "falling through", e.g.,

```
f 0 = 1
f n = 2 * f (n - 1)
```

but only in the sense that the second line has a silent "otherwise".

Comment: And there was a great debate in the Haskell committee (25 years ago) if there should be a non-silent "otherwise" in that case.  Phil Wadler was in favor of an "otherwise" most everyone else were against.